# случайно написал await и теперь не выдает ошику

Tags: c#, build-error, async-await

This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [project][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите `async` в заголовке метода. Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. И код здесь принято вставлять текстом.

Comment: Тем более если у вас `async void` и это не обработка события, то `async` однозначно лучше убрать в данном случае.

Comment: А так вообще код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это предупреждение вызывается из-за того, что вы не использовали в методе ключевое слово `await`. Но вам оно и не пригодится, так как нечего выполнять асинхоронно.

Просто уберите слово `async` из модификаторов метода `Main`.